# Appropriate loader to handle this file type. /index.esm.js

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, loader

I'm having a problem with my npm start pipeline after installing https://github.com/markmur/react-slack-feedback

If I run the pipeline I always get the error
`ERROR in ./~/react-slack-feedback/dist/index.esm.js
Module parse failed: /mnt/c/Work/........../app/node_modules/react-slack-feedback/dist/index.esm.js Unexpected token (1:16525)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import e from"react";import t,{css as o,keyframes as r,ThemeProvider as a}from"styled-components";function........`

The pipeline itself is running without problems since many months and various different packages are installed, but failure indicates that something in my webpack.dev.config.js is wrong for this file format, but I'm not sure how to change this correctly. Tried including

```
            {
                test: /sw\.esm.js$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader' }],
            },
```

but didn't effect the error.

My webpack.dev.config.js :

```
const path = require('path');
// ESLint: you will get an error here because of webpack being in
// devDependencies. However, the webpack README states it should be in dev.
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: {
        app: [
            // activate HMR for React
            'react-hot-loader/patch',
            // bundle the client for webpack-dev-server
            // and connect to the provided endpoint
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
            // bundle the client for hot reloading
            // only- means to only hot reload for successful updates
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            // the entry point of our app
            './app/index.jsx',
        ],
        main: './main/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        // the output bundle
        filename: '[name].js',
        // in contrast to the production config, we output into js/ directly.
        path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'js'),
        // necessary for HMR to know where to load the hot update chunks
        publicPath: '/static/js/',
    },
    // Integrate quickly build source maps into the resulting js file.
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    // webpack dev server config (for live and hot reloading)
    devServer: {
        // enable HMR on the server
        hot: true,
        // make it accessible from everywhere. nice for mobile testing.
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        allowedHosts: ['*'],
        disableHostCheck: true,
        // Django is running on port 8000, so when using the devServer default
        // (8080) it's easy to miss that you are on the wrong server in the
        // browser's URL bar, because they look very similar. Moving this to
        // 3000 because of that.
        port: 3000,
        // match the output path
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'js'),
        // match the output `publicPath`
        publicPath: '/static/js/',
        // Open up a proxy to the django runserver. API requests etc. need to
        // go through to the backend ;-)
        proxy: {
            '/': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8000',
                secure: false,
            },
        },
    },
    // What to do with each file type (js, jsx, sass, css,...)
    module: {
        rules: [
            // Used to reference the service worker for registering it. The
            // service worker is used to listen to push notifications.
            {
                test: /sw\.js$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader' }],
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                // Configured in .babelrc
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 2,
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            path: 'static/sass/postcss.config.js',
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            // SASS compiler config
                            outputStyle: 'expanded',
                            sourceComments: true,
                            sourceMapEmbed: true,
                            sourceMapContents: true,
                            includePaths: [
                                path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'sass'),
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    // ES6: when doing `import "foobar"`, webpack will look for "foobar.js"
    // file and, if not found, a "foobar.jsx" file. Hence, you don't have to
    // append the .js(x) file ending in the import statement.
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    plugins: [
        // enable HMR globally
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        // prints more readable module names in the browser console on HMR updates
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by updating `webpack-dev-server` & `webpack-cli` to their latest versions. In my case this was webpack-dev-server: 3.3.1 and webpack-cli: 3.3.2